# C# lambda expression joining 4 tables situation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am joining 4 tables (Productos, ProductosFotos, Marca, Categoria) to find the product by CategoriaId. The ProductoFotos table contains 3 images but I only need to show 1 of them. What do I need to do and not repeat the result for each image.

Here is my code:

```
var productoInCategoriaInDb = _productoRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Publicado == true && x.CategoriaId == id)
            .GroupJoin(
                _productoFotoRepository.GetAll(), <-- here take only one image
                p => p.ProductoId,
                pf => pf.ProductoId,
                (p, pf) => new { p, pf })
            .SelectMany(
                p => p.pf.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (p, pf) => new { p.p, pf })
            .GroupJoin(
                _marcaRepository.GetAll(),
                ppf => ppf.p.MarcaId,
                pm => pm.MarcaId,
                (ppf, pm) => new { ppf, pm })
            .SelectMany(
                ppfpm => ppfpm.pm.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (ppfpm, pm) => new { ppfpm.ppf, pm })
            .GroupJoin(
                _categoriaRepository.GetAll(),
                ppfpm => ppfpm.ppf.p.CategoriaId,
                pc => pc.CategoriaId,
                (ppfpm, pc) => new { ppfpm, pc })
            .SelectMany(
                ppfpmpc => ppfpmpc.pc.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (ppfpmpc, pc) => new ProductoBuscarViewModel
                {
                    Producto = ppfpmpc.ppfpm.ppf.p,
                    ProductoFoto = ppfpmpc.ppfpm.ppf.pf,
                    Marca = ppfpmpc.ppfpm.pm,
                    Categoria = pc
                }
            );
```

**Update**

[Relational contraints diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKHs.jpg)

Comment: Are your relationships defined using relational constraints? If so, then you don't need to write a query this way, you can instead query the collection members of your entities directly.

Comment: @Sty, I updated your edit to remove the "Thank you" altogether. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720 for more information about the reasoning behind this. Note that your edit was good; we'd just like to see a bit more removed.

Comment: Do you mean, that you have 3 images for the same Proveedor? In that case, what image do you want? Wich criteria do you need for get an image?

Comment: Got it @MikeMcCaughan :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using relational contraints @Dai

Comment: Yup, the Product/Producto has 3 different images and I want only the first one. @AlejandroPérezFals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
var productoInCategoriaInDb = from prod in _productoRepository.GetAll()
    join imag in _productoFotoRepository.GetAll()
        on p.ProductoId equals imag.ProductoId into imags
    from imag in imags.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join marca in _marcaRepository.GetAll()
        on prod.MarcaId equals marca.MarcaId into marcas
    from marca in marcas.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join cat in _categoriaRepository.GetAll()
        on cat.CategoriaId equals prod.CategoriaId into cats
    from cat in cats.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { prod, imag, marca, cat } by new { P = prod, M = marca, C = cat } into prodGroup
    select new ProductoBuscarViewModel(){
        Producto = prodGroup.Key.P
        ProductoFoto = prodGroup.FirstOfDefault().imag
        Marca = prodGroup.Key.M
        Categoria = prodGroup.Key.C
    }
```

This will generate a subselect with top(1) to get the first image of all with the same product. I proved it in LinqPad with similar entities. I usually put a bit field in the ProductoFoto entity to set the 'default' image of a Proveedor. Then filter the _productoFotoRepository.GetAll() to get only the default image. With that you dont need to call to a group by and the query will execute faster.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as correct, and upvote for it. Thanks!!

Comment: One more thing. In case the Producto not has images yet how I can handle this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: That is because `prodGroup.FirstOfDefault()` is null. You need to use `ProductoFoto = prodGroup.FirstOfDefault() == null ? null : prodGroup.FirstOfDefault().imag`

Comment: Also can be resolved like this from the view:

if(@item.ProductoFoto == null) { <p>Image not available</p> } else { <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ImagesFolder/")@item.ProductoFoto.Nombre" }